# How to remove border lines of dundas contorl

Tags: c#

how to remove border of dundas control chart.

[image]

Remove the border lines around the Chart control. Iam using dundas chart control(7.0 version) for olap. Is there any property to remove these lines.  Please help me to remove that lines.

Comment: Is this winforms?

Comment: no. it is a webpage. used to show dashboards

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: <DOCWC:OlapClient ID="OlapchartHorizantal1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="550px"
                            FrameStyle-BorderColor="Black" BackColor="Transparent" ForeColor="Black" >